# jest : unexpected token in renderer create

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

When I eun yarn test I am getting an error called unexpected token as shown in below screenshot
[image]

So I added preset in .bablelr also but it didnot work

```
{"presets": ["es2015","react-native"],"plugins": [] }
```

Please anyone help me to solve this